# Load template by groups Ion Auth in Code Igniter

Tags: authentication, acl, ion-auth

How do I show a template according to the login user by groups idand how do I restrict access to the controller according to user groups.

My controller :

```
public function index()
{
    if (!$this->ion_auth->in_group('admin'))
    {
        $this->template->administrator('dashboard/dashboard');
    }
    elseif (!$this->ion_auth->in_group('2'))
    {
        $this->template->admin('dashboard/dashboard');
    }
    elseif (!$this->ion_auth->in_group('3'))
    {
        $this->template->user('dashboard/dashboard');
    }
    elseif (!$this->ion_auth->in_group('members'))
    {
        $this->template->client('dashboard/dashboard');
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('account/sign_in', 'refresh');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying and asking, finally I get the correct results that I can use as in the following code :

```
public function index()
{

    if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in())
    {
        redirect('account/sign_in', 'refresh');
    }
    elseif ($this->ion_auth->is_admin())
    {
        $this->template->administrator('dashboard/dashboard');
        //View to Administrator
    }
    elseif($this->ion_auth->in_group('admin'))
    {
        $this->template->admin('dashboard/dashboard');
        //View to Admin
    }
    elseif($this->ion_auth->in_group('user'))
    {
        $this->template->user('dashboard/dashboard');
        //View to User
    }
    else
    {
        $this->template->client('dashboard/dashboard');
        //View to Client
    }
}
```

Hopefully this answer helpful and enjoy time to code...... :)